# Can Meteor live changes have animations?

Tags: meteor

How does Meteor handle live changes? For instance I don't want changes to be instantaneous, but with some kind of animation of sorts. If we place the items being changed using css animations/transitions does this work? What about jQuery animations for older browsers?

Comment: +1 interesting, this probably will require some implementation changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a working example of a simple animation with meteor.

The situation here is that we have a list of items. If the user clicks on any of those items the item will animate 20px to the left.

JS

```js
//myItem
Template.myItem.rendered = function(){
  var instance = this;
  if(Session.get("selected_item") === this.data._id){
    Meteor.defer(function() {  
      $(instance.firstNode).addClass("selected"); //use "instance" instead of "this"
    });
  }
};

Template.myItem.events({
  "click .myItem": function(evt, template){
    Session.set("selected_item", this._id);
  }
});


//myItemList
Template.myItemList.helpers({
  items: function(){
    return Items.find();
  }
});
```

Templates

```html
<template name="myItem">
  <div class="myItem">{{name}}</div>
</template>

<template name="myItemList">
  {{#each items}}
    {{> myItem}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

CSS

```css
.myItem { transition: all 200ms 0ms ease-in; }
.selected { left: -20px; }
```

Instead of using fancy CSS you can also animate with jQuery:

```js
Template.myItem.rendered = function(){
  if(Session.get("selected_item") === this.data._id){
    $(this.firstNode).animate({
      left: "-20px"
    }, 300);
  }
};
```

But then you need to remove the CSS code.

```css
.myItem { transition: all 200ms 0ms ease-in; }
.selected { left: -20px; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Note `if(Session.get("selected_item") === this.data._id)` didn't work for me; I had to modify the `rendered` function to include a line like this instead: `$('#'+Session.get("selected_item")).addClass("selected")`.

Comment: @TimBartsch I cannot find `Meteor.defer()` from the docs. What does it do?

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround like this:

```
<template name="foo">
  ..content..
  {{bar}}
</template>
```

In this case Meteor will call `Template.foo.bar` everytime this template gets rendered. So within this function you can do all kinds of Jquery or CSS3 animations (for example by adding a class to the templates div).

Comment: an example here would have been great. (notice how upvotes for "useful question" are a lot more than "answer is useful"). Maybe you can update your answer?

Answer (score 2):

For CSS transitions, there are two options you can go with:

```
1. Reactively: the Meteor way
2. Directly: the jQuery way
```

Here is a working example: 
http://bindle.me/blog/index.php/658/animations-in-meteor-state-of-the-game