# Why is Template.mytemplate.rendered getting triggered twice when trying to animate live changes in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have some issues figuring out how `Meteor.rendered` works exactly. I'm trying to animate a live change in Meteor, very much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861544/can-meteor-live-changes-have-animations) does. Whenever I click on an element, I want it to blink.

However, the template gets rendered twice every time an element is clicked, which in turn triggers the animation two times. Here is the code:

**Template**

```
<body>
  {{> myItemList}}
</body>

<template name="myItem">
  <div class="item {{selected}}">
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="myItemList">
  {{#each items}}
    {{> myItem}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
Template.myItemList.helpers({
  items: function () {
    return Items.find();
  }
});

Template.myItem.helpers({
  selected: function () {
    return Session.equals('selected', this._id) ? "selected" : "";
  }
});

Template.myItem.events({
  'click .item' : function () {
    Session.set('selected', this._id);
  }
});

Template.myItem.rendered = function () {
  $(".item.selected").fadeOut().fadeIn();
};
```

My understanding is that every time `Session.set` is called, every template that uses `Session.get` for the same key is re-runed, as explained in the documentation. So my guess is that somehow, `Session.equals` causes 2 reruns of the template, maybe? If I change the `selected` helper with this code:

```
Template.myItem.helpers({
  selected: function () {
    if (Session.get("selected")) === this._id)
      return "selected";
    else
      return "";
  }
});
```

Then the animation gets triggered 3 times instead of 2.

With all that in mind, my questions are:

1. Why is `Template.myItem.rendered` getting triggered twice? What exactly goes on behind the scenes?
2. How can I fix this to only have my animation triggered once?

### ANSWER DETAILS

So to comment on @Xyand solutions:

1. Moving the animations to the `click` event with a `Meteor.setTimeout()` definitely works, but felt a bit hacky to me.
2. The solution was actually quite simple, and already given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861544/can-meteor-live-changes-have-animations). The code looks like this:

   ```
   Template.myItem.rendered = function () {
     if (Session.equals('selected', this.data._id))
       $(this.firstNode).fadeOut().fadeIn();
   };
   ```

I first tried that on a different project that had a different template markup and it didn't work, this is why I created this minimal project to see where things went wrong. Turns out that for this to work, you absolutely need to have a sub-template `myItem` called inside the `myItemList` template. If the template looks like this,

```
<template name="myItemList">
  {{#each items}}
    <div class="item {{selected}}">
      <h4>{{name}}</h4>
      <p>{{description}}</p>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

and thus every helper function and the `rendered` function are called for the `myItemList` template, the code won't work because inside the `rendered` function, the template instance will have a `.data` attribute that is undefined.

Comment: How many instances of `myItem` do you have? (My guess is 3). I think that 2 are being re-rendered. One sets `selected` to `""` and the other to `"selected"`

Comment: Indeed, I do have 3 objects in the Collection. So you're saying that the template gets re-rendered once when the previous selected item loses its `"selected"` class and once again when the newly selected item gains the `"selected"` class, did I get that correctly? If so, how do I make sure that the animation only gets triggered once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template gets rendered twice because two different instances of the same template get rendered. One that changes `selected` to `"selected"` and another that changes it to `""`. This also explains why you have 3 renders when you switch `equals` to `get`.

Mixing imperative javascript with declarative is always a mess. So here are my two suggestions:

1. Add an `if` inside the `rendered` function to make sure you call the transition only in the selected item template instance.
2. Move the transition to the event itself. You might need to use `Meteor.setTimeout`.

Placing the transition in `rendered` might not be the best option as it will happen every time the template renders. For instance if `name` changes. Think what would happen when the code gets longer...

Comment: I'm editing the question with a few explanations on how your inputs made this work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, template gets rerendered every time client fetch another portion of data, whether it's because the data has changed or because of latency.

Thankfully, there's another function that's only called once when the template is created, that is - `template.created`. It has the downside that you cannot access view elements from there, as they weren't yet created. You can, however, mark the template as "fresh" and schedule animation on the next render:

```
var animate;

Template.myItem.created = function() {
    animate = true;
};

Template.myItem.rendered = function() {
    if(animate) {
        animate = false;
        ... // Do the animation here.
    }
};
```

**Update:**

```
Template.myItem.events({
  'click .item' : function () {
    animate = true;
    Session.set('selected', this._id);
  },
});
```

Comment: Not sure it would help him. He wants the animation triggered when item is clicked. Your proposal would animate only once, as soon as the item is rendered for the first time.

Comment: @Xyand is right on this one, the animation doesn't get triggered at each click with this code.

Comment: But you're right, I've got the use case a bit wrong. Moving transformation to event handler is a better idea.