# Meteor #each: animate entry of new items

Tags: animation, meteor, iron-router

I have a simple chat application I'm using to learn Meteor.  I really like the aesthetic of fading new messages in on other chat platforms I've seen.

Basically, I want an elegant solution to **fade in new data rows within my `#each` block.**

Here's what I've tried:

```
{{#each messages}}
    <li class="message"> {{ username }} says: {{ message }} </li>
{{/each}}
```

---

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    Messages.find();  //reactive data dependency.
    $('li.message:last-child').hide().fadeIn();
}
```

But the problem is that it only fades in the *second* to last `li.message`.  I presume this is because the autorun is running before the DOM interaction is complete.

Am I even doing this right?  Is there a way to animate *new* data rows in the `#each` helper?

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861544/can-meteor-live-changes-have-animations) but it seems to rely on a user click event.  I would prefer the non-interactive version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an elegant solution; in fact, I don't know why I didn't think of this sooner.  However, I'm going to wait on accepting my own answer for a while in case someone has a really good contribution.

Essentially, my solution is to wrap the content within the `#each` block in a different template, and use that template's `rendered` hook to apply my jQuery animation.

```
{{#each messages}}
    {{>message}}
{{/each}}

....

<template name="message">
    <li class="message"> {{ username }} says: {{ message }} </li>
</template>
```

---

```
Template.message.rendered = function() {
    this.$(".message").hide().fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: You might also want to set the message to be hidden by default and wrap the fadein in a timeout of 0 ms, which basically means defer until after the actual render. These two additions should ensure there is no flickering in edge cases.